Angular HostListener does not work before focusing on page
I have a component, where we have a button
There is a simple HostListener, which will display a notification on shortcut (ALT + Q)
  @HostListener('window:keydown.alt.q', ['$event'])
  displayNotification(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'success',
      detail: 'Finished',
      life: 5
    });
   }

Everything starts working only if I perform a click on the component, before that the notification does not appear
What is the cause and the appropriate solution?
Thanks!

That is how it is, because without focusing on why the application should the shortcut trigger, you could trigger a focus after the view is initialized.
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  @HostListener('window:keydown.alt.q', ['$event'])
  displayNotification(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('shortcut!');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    window.focus();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
